# Dealing with a custom section in package.json

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, configuration

I'm having a `package.json` file with a custom section. So, basically, something such as:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": { ... },
  "mySection": { ... }
}
```

Accessing this custom section is quite easy: Simply `require` the `package.json` file and access the `mySection` property. That's it.

Now, I would like to have some validation on this: Check that some mandatory keys are actually there, provide default values to missing values that are defined as optional, check types, ...

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

PS: I know that, e.g. for validating, I could use a JSON schema. This would solve my problem at least partially, but JSON schemas is not really ... well, easily usable. For many cases, it's IMHO a little bit over-sized.

Comment: Why is JSON schema not usable and over-sized? It is easily usable from many programming languages and tools (http://json-schema.org/implementations.html) and the specification is really short (http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html).

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the easiest way would be to just write a small validation function that would assign defaults and check for missing properties. I would prefer this way instead of adding a dependency of any sort for just a simple one off task (if that is a case)

Comment: Well, if you had a general way of how to accomplish this task (e.g. a dedicated module) you could re-use things.

Comment: I really think this would be an overkill. I would just define a json with expected properties as I would want them to appear in `mySection` and validation functions for values. All you need after that is a simple recursive function to traverse the two objects (target and validation) and apply those validation functions on target properites. Bam, easy and functional without any rubbish dependencies. You can then go fancy and publish it as your own mini json validation module. Neat eay :)